# Multiple regex in Python findall

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a string : "She has an excellent command on the topicsOnly problem is clarity in EnglishHer confidence is very good in RUSSian and H2O"

If observed properly, this string doesnt have any punctuation. I am primarily focusing on putting the periods.
"She has an excellent command on the topics. Only problem is clarity in English. Her confidence is very good in RUSSian and H2O"
I can use a regex and findall to get a list of relevant words. I tried using something like this, but its not giving the desired result. I would like a computationally efficient code.

```
import re

text = "She has an excelllent command on the topicsOnly problem is clarity in EnglishHer confidence is very good in RUSSian and H2O"

r = re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([A-Z][a-z]+)', text)
```

Comment: `re.sub(r'([a-z])([A-Z])', r'\1. \2', text)`

Comment: Your first and last alternatives are the same, aren't they?

Comment: Your regexp will match all words. How is that supposed to help you find where the periods belong?

Answer (score 1):

I tried something like that with the PCRE engine : `(\p{Ll}+)(\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)`

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/tqIcdS/1

The idea is to use the `\p{L}` to find any word character (like `\w`) but with handling unicode chars that might have accents (ex: "*Le pain, je l'ai mangéEnsuite j'ai bu un verre de vin*").

- `\p{Ll}` matches a lowercase unicode word character.
- `\p{Lu}` matches an uppercase unicode word character.

I also captured the characters before and after to match the whole word.

Unfortunately, *Python*'s default *re* library doesn't support it.

But thanks to Wiktor's comment below, you could use the *PyPi regex* library: https://pypi.org/project/regex/

Comment: Python `re` does not support Unicode property classes, but Python PyPi `regex` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in Python `re` for both ASCII and fully Unicode-aware solutions:

```py
import re, sys

pLu = '[{}]'.format("".join([chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).isupper()]))
pLl = '[{}]'.format("".join([chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).islower()]))

text = "She has an excelllent command on the topicsOnly problem is clarity in EnglishHer confidence is very good in RUSSian and H2O"
print( re.sub(fr'({pLl})({pLu})', r'\1. \2', text) ) # Unicode-aware
# => She has an excelllent command on the topics. Only problem is clarity in English. Her confidence is very good in RUSSian and H2O
print( re.sub(fr'([a-z])([A-Z])', r'\1. \2', text) ) # ASCII only
# => She has an excelllent command on the topics. Only problem is clarity in English. Her confidence is very good in RUSSian and H2O
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/TuYjCW).

The main idea is to match and capture a lowercase letter and then an uppercase letter (`([a-z])([A-Z])`) and replace with Group 1 value + `.` and space and then Group 2 value, where `\1` and `\2` are backreferences to these group values.